# Ember.view not available on Ember namespace

Tags: ember.js

I am using ember-2.0.1 and trying to build an app.

```
var indexView = Ember.View.create({
    templateName:'index'
});
```

Ember.View is undefined.. 
Do I need to include any seed file for View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Views` are not part of Ember in versions higher than 1.13:

> Views have been removed in Ember 2.0. Components, which provide better
>   isolation and scoping semantics, fulfill the use-cases views were
>   introduced for.

http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/08/13/ember-2-0-released.html